# React Native app cannot connect to local development server when running on physical iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native, metro-bundler

i'm trying to run a react native app on my physical ios device from xcode, but it seems like it cannot connect to the metro server. i'm getting the error

```
2022-07-22 08:51:39.307312-0400 Wam[18995:1465079] Task <39C43637-F7A7-4C7D-A1AF-31C96E7D9EDE>.<1> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x2838a02a0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: lo0, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <39C43637-F7A7-4C7D-A1AF-31C96E7D9EDE>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <39C43637-F7A7-4C7D-A1AF-31C96E7D9EDE>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8081/status, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8081/status, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

i noticed that the metro server url that the app is using is `http://localhost:8081/status` whereas for a fresh rn project on the same version, the app uses `http://{MY_LOCAL_IP}:8081/status`.

whatever causes the app to replace `localhost` with the local IP address no longer works for my RN project and i'm not sure why.

here are the diffs of all of the ios files that were modified to accommodate for packages like codepush, firebase, expo and push notifications

- [info.plist](https://www.diffchecker.com/rM6aEFMT)
- [podfile](https://www.diffchecker.com/ThhipOHV)
- [AppDelegate.h](https://www.diffchecker.com/RZutPwIg)
- [AppDelegate.m](https://www.diffchecker.com/DcIvVdBH)

Comment: ```<key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key><true/>``` I have this additional permission in my info.plist. Maybe it could help resolve your issue. I did not try running my code after removing this permission so cannot say for sure but everything else looks the same

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work. still getting the same issue

Comment: what i've noticed from the error is that new react native projects don't use http://localhost:8081, they use http://{LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS}:8081. so i think the issue is that something is hindering that substitution of localhost -> IP address